# Pipe the results of whos command into a tlist

Tags: pipe, scilab

I want to export the results of `whos` command into a `tlist` inside Scilab:

```
Name                     Type           Size           Bytes        

%_k                      constant       1x1            0            
%_LG_all                 string         141x1          0            
%_lhs                    constant       1x1            0            
%_nams                   string         133x1          0            
%_nams_all               string         141x1          0            
%_nams_global            string         8x1            0            
%_rhs                    constant       1x1            0            
%_sz                     string         1x1            0            
%_typ                    constant       1x1            0
```

In Unix lingo it is called `pipe`ing done with `|` operator. But I don't know how to do this in Scilab. I would appreciate if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the source code of `whos` itself (it is written in the Scilab language) :

```
--> edit whos
```

by adding an output to this function

```
function out=whos(%_opt,%_sel)
```

and the following instruction at line 118

```
out(%_k) = struct("name",%_nams_all(%_k),"type",%_typn,...
                  "dimensions",%_sz,"bytes",%_vol_all(%_k)*8);
```

you will get what you want. Of course, you can also create a tlist...

S.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but why this is not the default behavior? I think Scilab has a lot of inconsistencies which could be resolved if there was a real repository with issue tracking and pull requests...

Comment: The place for issues and wishes is http://bugzilla.scilab.org. Pull requests are at http://codereview.scilab.org

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wish we could have you here on SO more often. you just solved two of my main issues. With this `whos` thing now I can manipulate variables without defining them as global.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very ugly workaround. There is a `diary` function which exports the last couple of `sdout` entries to a file. By using regular expression and some file magic  I could get the `whos` output as a matrix:

```
WhosExp = "/([\%\_\#\!\$\?a-zA-Z]+[\%\_\#\!\$\?a-zA-Z0-9]*)\s+(constant|polynomial|function|handle|string|boolean|list|rational|state\-space|sparse|boolean sparse|hypermat|st|ce|fptr|pointer|size implicit|library|int8|uint8|int16|uint16|int32|uint32|\_EObj|\_EVoid)\*?\s+((\d+)x(\d+)|\?)?\s+(\d+)/"

TempFile = TMPDIR + '/TempDiary.txt';
clc;
diary(TempFile)
whos;
diary(0)
clc;

TempID = mopen(TempFile, 'rt'); 
TempInfo = fileinfo(TempFile)
TempString = mgetstr(TempInfo(1), TempID);
mclose(TempID);
mdelete(TempFile);
[start, final, match, foundString] = regexp(TempString, WhosExp);
```

The `foundString` is the matrix/list which can be turned into a `tlis` if required.

**P.S.** it is really sad that the Scilab community is so deserted. Every time I ask a question I answer myself.